# Why i can't use .toString to this.props? reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I'm trying to use the react-beutiful-dnd, which accepts strings as it's components ids. When i use `<Droppable droppableId={this.props.id.toString()}>` it returns an error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

```js
//App.js
//...
render(){
    return(
        <AppsComponent id={1} />
//...
//AppsComponent.js
//...
render(){
    return(
        <Draggable key={this.props.id.toString()} draggableId={this.props.id.toString()}>
//...
```

Why?

Comment: id is not a string. It is undefined, make sure the props are passed correctly.

Comment: If i log this.props.id to the console, returns a number.

Comment: Can you provide the full code then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try without `toString`:

`<Droppable droppableId={'droppable-' + this.props.id}>`

For example:

```
var n = 5;
console.log("a = " + n); // a = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to do toString().

You can see the working sample here I had created.

https://codesandbox.io/s/ovjm8y9vvy